# Работа с каталогами в субдомене

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Как произвести запись файлов в поддомен? Например скрипт был запущен с сайта example.ru, и нужно что бы этот скрипт записал (удалил и т.д) файл находящийся на поддомене.

```
$directory = "subdomain.example.ru/cat";
$dir = opendir($directory);
```

Так не выходит. С указанием протокола тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Домены (и пути в них) — это в DNS и HTTP. Файлы — в файловой системе. Это два разных множества (ну или графа, как представить).

Как адрес в HTTP (включая схему, хост, порт и путь) преобразуется в адрес (путь) в файловой системе зависит от конфигурации сервера. Узнайте ее для Вашего хостера (оно у всех разное) и поймете что за путь Вам нужно указать в `opendir()`.

Скажем, я у себя, на одном своем сервере, организовывал файловую систему так: (это чисто пример)

- `/srv/example.org/htdocs/` — для `http://example.org/`
- `/srv/example.org/ssldocs/bar/` — для `https://example.org/bar/`
- `/srv/foo.example.org/htdocs/baz/` — для `http://foo.example.org/baz/`

Но может быть по-всякому, например, `http://foo.example.org/` → `/var/www/org/example/foo/`, или вообще как угодно. Поэтому уточняйте у техподдержки или системного администратора Вашего хостинг-провайдера. Или, если хоститесь сами (и не знаете где это настроено) — указывайте какой софт используете на сервере и попробуем выяснить это из файлов конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Всё получилось.

Answer (score -2):

Если у Вас сервер Windjws, то там будет один каталог http, а если *nix, там тоже будет http и еще куча каталогов, но сайт будет расположен в http, поэтому написать надо просто:

```
  $directory = "cat";

  $dir = opendir($directory);
```